# What line are webpack refering to?

Tags: webpack

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '_' in '/asdfdas'
     @ ./src/app/file.js 1:540-569
```

What is meant by `1:540-569`?

The file is not minified. What does the `1` mean? And `540-569`? Is it error "somewhere" between these lines? There is no `_` on line 540.

First line is:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
```

Comment: can you plz put content of `file.js` in post

Comment: @vinayakj. It's 11842 lines. Secret stuff.

Comment: how about line no. 1, line nos bet 540-569

Comment: @vinayakj. I've updated the question.

Comment: ohk its webpack generated file, I didnt see that..

Comment: Yes. But no error is given in the project the file is generated from.

Comment: I see.. see if these links help you..http://tomasalabes.me/blog/web-development/2016/04/30/Webpack-Series-Part-1.html https://gist.github.com/STRML/2117f574726bdf0b8d58

Comment: Perfect. I'll readem. Thanks for the help